# Why does wc command in execvp() return the wrong results when taking input from a pipe in my shell?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

I'm working on writing a shell in C for learning purposes and I'm trying to allow for a variable number of pipes. In general, it seems to work great. But I noticed a problem with the `wc` command.

When I pipe some output of another program into `wc` like `ls | wc` it always returns
`1    3    35` no matter what I pipe into it. Other commands work as expected when I pipe into them. In my normal `zsh` shell `wc` works fine. I'm struggling to find the problem. I've tried adding `waitpid` after the forks but no dice.

Here's the main shell loop in the `main` function:

```
while (1) {
        printf("\033[31;1mshell:\033[0m ");

        line = read_cmds();

        if (strstr(line, "|")) {
            // check for pipes first
            pipe_exec(line);
        } else {
            // we have a single command
            tokens = split(line, " \t\r\n");
            if (*tokens != NULL) shell_exec(tokens);
            free(tokens);
        }
    }
```

Here is the function that loops through the commands:

```
void pipe_exec(char *line)
{
    int in, status;
    int pipe_no; // keep track of ptr to bring it back to free 
    int pfd[2];
    pid_t rc;
    char **cmd, **pipe_cmds;
    
    // split takes a string and splits into array of strings based on delimiter
    pipe_cmds = split(line, "|"); 

    in = 0;
    pipe_no = 0;
    while (*pipe_cmds) {
        cmd = split(*pipe_cmds, " \t\r\n");

        if (pipe(pfd) < 0) perror("pipe");

        make_proc(in, pfd[1], cmd);
        close(pfd[1]);
        in = pfd[0];
        pipe_cmds++; // move ptr ahead one
        pipe_no++;
    }
    // move pointer back and free
    pipe_cmds -= pipe_no;
    free(pipe_cmds);

    rc = fork();
    if (rc == 0) {
        if (in != 0) dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
        execvp(*cmd, cmd);
    } 
}
```

And then the `make_proc` function that the above function calls:

```
void make_proc(int in, int out, char **cmd)
{
    pid_t rc;
    rc = fork();
    if (rc  == 0) {
        if (in != STDIN_FILENO) {
            dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != STDOUT_FILENO) {
            dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(out);
        }
        execvp(*cmd, cmd);
    } 
}
```

I took out some of the error checking to save space here.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try using `ls | cat` to see what input the second process is receiving.

Comment: @barmar `ls | cat` seems to be working correctly. It returns all the 7 items in the directory. I tried `ls | cat | wc` but to no avail. I'll keep working on it. Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `wc` would work differently.

Comment: Try using `/usr/bin/wc`

Comment: @Barmar still returns the wrong data. Really strange. I haven't implemented `cd` yet. I'm going to do that and see how it works in other directories.

Comment: What if you do `ls | true`. That should produce no output, is that what you see?

Comment: `cd` shouldn't matter. `wc` should receive the same input as `cat`. If `cat` works, then `wc` should work as well.

Comment: @Barmar `ls | true` doesn't give any output. And you're right, using `ls | wc` in other directories returns the same wrong data.

Comment: I suggest using system call tracing on the `wc` process to see what it's actually reading.

Comment: Use the shell tag when you're writing code in shell languages, not when you're writing a C program that happens to be a shell -- there's no particularly meaningful difference between problems encountered writing C programs that aren't shells and those that are; you're using the same functions and they behave the same ways.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good point. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the last command twice and pipe its first instance to the second. Adding something like:

```
    while (*pipe_cmds) { 
        cmd = split(*pipe_cmds, " \t\r\n");
        if (!pipe_cmds[1]) {
            break;
        }

        if (pipe(pfd) < 0) perror("pipe");

        make_proc(in, pfd[1], cmd);
        close(pfd[1]);
        in = pfd[0];
        pipe_cmds++; // move ptr ahead one
        pipe_no++;
    }
```

would prevent the unnecessary instance, although I would rather have refactored this function a bit.

Comment: Yup this does it! Thanks. Yeah I agree. Now that I know what's going on, I'll refactor it.